# Execute Store Command Entity Framewrok

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Hello I am using Entity Framework and I am using the ExecuteStoreCommand to do a query against the database. well I am basically calling a user defined function.

This is the call:

string result = m.ExecuteStoreQuery (SQL).FirstOrDefault();

I query the User Defined Function and I get the following result.

2.09,2.06,2.06,2.0098,2.04,2.04,2.04,2.04,2.04,2,2.1,2.04,2.04,2.04

The return type for the user defined function is

RETURNS Varchar(200). The result above is from the same cell.

When I execute the code from MVC controller I get the following error.The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive types.

What datatype I should be using instead of string.
 Any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the return type is not only a string.
On the SQL Server side, try to surround the code of your query with:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

<your current sql code>

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Maybe EF is getting the rows affected in the result and gets messed up.